# Connection with FTP via RSE on FTP

Tags: eclipse, ftp

Im running eclipse RSE on Ubuntu 12.

Whenever Im trying to establish connection with remote server Im getting error :

> 425 Could not open data connection to port 50011: Connection timed out

Any ides please?

Thanks in advance

Dom

Comment: Why is there PHP in the question tag?

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling passive mode for FTP.

In the Remote Systems View, right click on your system and select Properties.  In the Connector Services page, click the FTP Settings service and change the value of the passive property to true using the drop down.